# how to restrict the drag and drop of a row with in that table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Iam getting problem when you are drag and drop a row..it is coming out of the table instead of with in that table..how to make it as drag and drop with in that table...can anyone help me

```js
$('td, th', '#sortFixed').each(function () {
    var cell = $(this);
    cell.width(cell.width());
});

$('#sortFixed tbody').sortable().disableSelection();
```

```html
<table style="border:1px solid black;" id="sortFixed" class="grid">
    <caption>Kurt Vonnegut novels</caption>
    <thead >
        <tr><th>Year</th><th>Title</th><th>Grade</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1969</td><td>Slaughterhouse-Five</td><td>A+</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1952</td><td>Player Piano</td><td>B</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1963</td><td>Cat's Cradle</td><td>A+</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1973</td><td>Breakfast of Champions</td><td>C</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1965</td><td>God Bless You, Mr. Rosewater</td><td>A</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Ravi, was my answer useful? Kind regards

Comment: thanks for answer..but its not working for my code

Answer (score 0):

Just try to put the id = "sortFixed" into the tbody. It is working for me.

```
  <script>
    $( function() {
    $( "#sortFixed" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortFixed" ).disableSelection();
  } );
  </script>

 <table style="border:1px solid black;" id="oldSortFixed" class="grid">
    <caption>Kurt Vonnegut novels</caption>
    <thead >
        <tr><th>Year</th><th>Title</th><th>Grade</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="sortFixed">
        <tr><td>1969</td><td>Slaughterhouse-Five</td><td>A+</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1952</td><td>Player Piano</td><td>B</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1963</td><td>Cat's Cradle</td><td>A+</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1973</td><td>Breakfast of Champions</td><td>C</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1965</td><td>God Bless You, Mr. Rosewater</td><td>A</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here in a html working file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $( function() {
    $( "#sortFixed" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortFixed" ).disableSelection();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

 <table style="border:1px solid black;" id="oldSortFixed" class="grid">
    <caption>Kurt Vonnegut novels</caption>
    <thead >
        <tr><th>Year</th><th>Title</th><th>Grade</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="sortFixed">
        <tr><td>1969</td><td>Slaughterhouse-Five</td><td>A+</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1952</td><td>Player Piano</td><td>B</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1963</td><td>Cat's Cradle</td><td>A+</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1973</td><td>Breakfast of Champions</td><td>C</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1965</td><td>God Bless You, Mr. Rosewater</td><td>A</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: $("#fmeaTemplateBody").sortable();
   $("table #fmeaTemplateBody").sortable({ 
  update: function(event, ui) {  
      $('#fmeaTemplateBody  tr').each(function() {
          $(this).children('td:first-child').html($(this).index()+1)
          
      });
  },
  axis:"y",
  containment:"parent",
  tolerance:"intersect",
  helper: fixHelper
  }).disableSelection();
   var tolerance= $( "#fmeaTemplateBody" ).sortable( "option", "tolerance" );
   $( "#fmeaTemplateBody" ).sortable( "option", "tolerance", "pointer" ); Actually this is my code its not working...